# Get list of files changed before a particular date of last release or any commit ID

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, svn2git

We are migrating from SVN to GIT and in SVN we have a revision number which we are using to get the list of files changed up to a given HEAD version using ant scripts.

How can we do this in a similar way for GIT?

Thanks in advance,
Devidutta Panda

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question here then below should work

```
 git log --before='yyyy-mm-dd'
```

You can use --before or --after flag as your requirement. And for your specific requirement i feel this should work.

```
git log --after='yyyy-mm-dd' | git show <commit id> --no-patch
```

Comment: we need the files changed after a date, also will it work with last commit id